# Parsing Integer wont work

Tags: android

Can someone check my code? I am having my calculation for the score using `TextView` and `EditText`, i also declared Integers for the variables, but when i run my code, it gives me error when parsing integer. Thanks in advance. Also check my Log cat for more info.  Here's my code:

```
 initControls();
      }
      private void initControls()
      {
          amount1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount1);
          amount2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount2);
          amount3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount3);
          result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
          calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.finish);
          calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
          {public void onClick
          (View  v) { calculate();}});
      }
      private void calculate()
      {

          if(amount1.getText().toString().equals(null))
          {
          x=0;
          }
          else
              amount1.getText().toString();
              x=Integer.parseInt(amount1.getText().toString());

      if(amount2.getText().toString().equals(null)) {
          y=0; 
      }
      else
          amount2.getText().toString();
          y=Integer.parseInt(amount2.getText().toString());

     if(amount3.getText().toString().equals(null)) {
          v=0;
      }
     else
    amount3.getText().toString();
      v=Integer.parseInt(amount3.getText().toString());
      {
          z=x+y+v;
          result.setText(Integer.toString(z));
      }
```

Here's my Log cat:

```
08-16 16:15:51.794: W/dalvikvm(224): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
08-16 16:15:51.794: E/AndroidRuntime(224): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:353)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:323)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at drj.thesis.tridi.Maingame.calculate(Maingame.java:70)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at drj.thesis.tridi.Maingame.access$0(Maingame.java:54)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at drj.thesis.tridi.Maingame$1.onClick(Maingame.java:52)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-16 16:15:51.824: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 16:15:51.857: I/dalvikvm(224): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-16 16:15:51.864: E/dalvikvm(224): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fairly clear:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
```

You're trying to parse an empty string. You need to work out *why* you're trying to parse an empty string.

I suspect this is a large part of it:

```
 if(amount1.getText().toString().equals(null))
 {
    x=0;
 }
 else
    amount1.getText().toString();
    x=Integer.parseInt(amount1.getText().toString());
```

You should have braces around your `else` block so that *both* statements are in it:

```
 if(amount1.getText().toString().equals(null))
 {
    x=0;
 }
 else
 {
    amount1.getText().toString();
    x=Integer.parseInt(amount1.getText().toString());
 }
```

... although the first statement in the `else` block looks pointless to me.

I'd actually expect `amount1.getText()` to *already* return a string though, making the `toString()` call unnecessary (maybe not; this could be an Android facet I don't know about) but I'd never expect the result to be equal to null. Perhaps you meant to compare with "" like this:

```
 if(amount1.getText().toString().equals(""))
 {
    x=0;
 }
 else
 {
    // Removed pointless call to amount1.getText().toString()
    x=Integer.parseInt(amount1.getText().toString());
 }
```

(You can use `amount1.getText().toString().getLength() == 0` to check for an empty string too. It's a matter of preference which you pick.)

You've got the same problem just below this as well, suggesting you should probably extract a method to perform this conditional parsing.

Additionally, you should *really* fix your indentation. Indenting code properly makes a huge difference to code readability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helps me, im sorry coz im new to android.

Answer (score 2):

First you should check your null string using string length function.

### like

`if(amount1.getText().toString().length == 0)`

second thing you need to put `{ }` brackets in else loop

### Example

```
if(amount1.getText().toString().length() == 0)
{
   x=0;
}
else
{
   x=Integer.parseInt(amount1.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

Your code trying to parse `Empty Text('')` which can't be parsed. Please write that parsing code in else part with `{}` bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Empty Text( '' ) can't be parsed as a number/integer.